# Maxmind lookup working locally, but not on dev server

Tags: ashx, maxmind

I'm doing a look up on Maxmind (a service that can provide geolocation info based on an IP address passed to it).  I do this via an .ashx handler.  When I call this locally, it works fine, however on our dev server it's failing.  I get a JSON response from the service and it returns 'blank' for the location like this:

```
{"RegionId":null,"RegionName":"","RegionCode":"","CountryId":null,"CountryName":"","CountryCode":"","Latitude":0,"Longitude":0}
```

The strange thing is that on the dev server I have a different .ashx handler (being called from a different domain) that is working, and it uses exactly the same underlying dll's as the one that's failing (I've copied the dll's into the website of the broken handler).  The actual call to the Maxmind service looks like this:

var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://geoip.maxmind.com:8010/b?l=*ourkey*=" + ipAddress)

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely a configuration problem, have you checked to see whether your database connection strings are set up correctly for the ashx handler on the dev server?  :-)